# Paypal Webhook get Email from request data

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, django-paypal

I am building an endpoint that receives the webbhooks from paypal. At the event `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` a mail should be sent. Of course the email has to be filtered from the request data. However, neither in the request.META nor in the eventbody such information can be found. The situation is different for the `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED`. There you can find the email in the eventbody. But since this is a completely different event and not an indicator for a successful payment, I cannot use this.
Does anyone have experience with this, how to use the email for`PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`
to get the email of the Paypal user account?

Comment: If it's not in the event data, it's not in the event data. Store the information from another source in your own database.